# Phaser - Applying a mask to a group with sprites inside

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to create a basic slot machine while studying phaser and so far I've come up with loading four rows of three sprites, and scrolling them upwards. Ideally, only three rows are visible (9 sprites in total), the fourth row is just the buffer so the top doesn't weirdly disappear when I move it to the bottom.

All of my sprites are added to a group, with the intention of masking the top and the bottom of the group.

[image]

Here's my code so far (shortened):

`this.comboBase` is the base sprite, the background of the slot machine.

```
var comboMask = this.game.add.graphics(this.comboBase.x, this.comboBase.y);
comboMask.beginFill(0xffffff);
comboMask.drawRect(this.comboBase.x, this.comboBase.y + 170, this.comboBase.width, 85);
console.log(comboMask.width);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  var arrowRight;
  var arrowDown;
  var arrowLeft;
  if (ranNum == 1) {
    arrowRight = this.game.add.sprite(this.comboBase.x - 85, arrowY, 'ui');
    arrowDown = this.game.add.sprite(this.comboBase.x, arrowY, 'ui');
    arrowLeft = this.game.add.sprite(this.comboBase.x + 85, arrowY, 'ui');        
    this.comboRouletteList1.push(arrowRight);
    this.comboRouletteList2.push(arrowDown);
    this.comboRouletteList3.push(arrowLeft);
  }
  else if (ranNum == 2) {
    // Different arrangement     
    this.comboRouletteList1.push(arrowDown);
    this.comboRouletteList2.push(arrowLeft);
    this.comboRouletteList3.push(arrowRight);
  }
  else if (ranNum == 3) {
    //Different arrangement     
    this.comboRouletteList1.push(arrowLeft);
    this.comboRouletteList2.push(arrowRight);
    this.comboRouletteList3.push(arrowDown);
  }

  arrowY += 85;
  arrowRight.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
  arrowDown.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
  arrowLeft.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
  arrowRight.frameName = 'ui_specialR.png';
  arrowDown.frameName = 'ui_specialD.png';
  arrowLeft.frameName = 'ui_specialL.png';
  this.comboRouletteGroup.add(arrowRight);
  this.comboRouletteGroup.add(arrowDown);
  this.comboRouletteGroup.add(arrowLeft);
}    

this.comboRouletteGroup.add(this.comboTop);
this.comboRouletteGroup.mask = comboMask;
```

But instead of hiding the bottom row, it made the entire group invisible.

I've tried changing the coordinates of the `drawRect` and the inital x/y around, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where I went wrong, and since it's invisible, I'm left guessing.

```
var comboMask = this.game.add.graphics(this.comboBase.x, this.comboBase.y + this.comboBase.height);
comboMask.beginFill(0xffffff);
comboMask.drawRect(comboMask.x, comboMask.y, this.comboBase.width, 100);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Afaik, sprites added later will cover earlier sprites, so all you need to do is add the 12 slot sprites, then the mask sprites, then simply change the position and image of the 12 slot sprites as needed.